# How to backup and restore Photoshop settings?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac

I am going to format my computer and I would like to back-up my Photoshop preferences along with the patterns and gradients I created.

Is there a way to back these up and import them all to the new installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [site: How to transfer Mac OS X Application Data](http://www.procata.com/blog/archives/2007/02/16/how-to-transfer-mac-os-x-application-data-between-computers/) is a bit old (2007) but it explains how to move application data and everything else you will need before formatting. Example: your Keychain file and your application data (Photoshop is an application) and settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

If you want to back-up Brushes, Patterns, Styles, Custom Shapes, etc... go to Edit > Preset Manager, and then a box will appear where you can load or save your preferences in a folder.

If you want to back-up your custom shortcuts go to Edit > Keyboard Shortcut, and then it will appear a box where you can load or save the current shortcuts in a file.

You can find more on backing up [Photoshop settings here.](http://www.prophotoshow.net/2008/11/05/how-to-backup-photoshop-settings/)